# Alternative to dynamic SQL query in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm looking to use SSRS for report generation in an app and am finding that using datasets with SQL defined within the SSRS report to be quite restrictive. As far as I can see, I could get around that by actually passing the SQL query to the report as a parameter and set the dataset to use that parameter as the SQL query. I do know dynamic SQL of the sort is usually frowned upon, but I need to see what my options are.

Some background here, my reasoning is that I have some very complex queries, and within my PHP app I have a lot of constructs (joins, subqueries, etc.) abstracted out, making it much easier to formulate queries and also re-usable clauses accross different parts of the app. I could probably achieve the same in the report builder using functions (would still need dynamic sql), but I'd still be duplicating a bunch of stuff I already have in PHP (bear in mind the specific language is irrelevant) since I need some of those same SQL constructs in my application. I also don't want to use stored procs, from past experience I've found them to be a pain to work with once queries get very complicated and you have a lot of different possible conditions, it gets ugly. And dynamic SQL in stored procs is a nightmare to debug, beside making you lose the performance benefits of using stored procs.

So what I'm curious about is what are the performance implications of passing a SQL string to the report as opposed to having the query inline (bearing in mind I would not be using stored procs no matter what). Would it somehow make the query slower, or would it be the equivalent of executing the query in PHP? Secondly, what are the other problems/risks associated with this practice? Provided I sanitize the SQL prior to passing it in, would there be any other major security risks to doing this? Thirdly, is there an alternative I'm not thinking about that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

I would mainly see as problem sql injection. If you can pass a query then anyone can do it.

Why not really using stored procedure, it's compiled and even if dynamic sql is not the best, it could Worth it probably.

By the way are you sure your query is so complicated it should be constructed? Isn't it a problem with sql itselfs?

Have you thought about function (but with dynamic of course).

There is a lots of solution and if i used ssrs to pass some parts of my query, it was always something boolean with no possibility of sql injection

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that all the parameters should be sanitizable, they'd have to be ints/dates/booleans, making it easy for me to sanitize. Then if my reports are embedded, I'm assuming there's a way to prevent the running of reports directly via the URL, in which case nobody else could pass in whatever SQL they want, at best they could try to inject something in a parameter, but I'd be sanitizing them so it wouldn't work.